# javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unable to parse TLS packet header in urlconnection.connect()

Tags: android-studio, httprequest

```
URL url = new URL("https://IP:8006/Calculator/product");
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.connect();
```

Getting the below exception in adroid-studio on url connect. Kindly help me resolve this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to solve your issue :

1. Use http instead of https. So, the used URL will be: `"http://IP:8006/Calculator/product"`
2. Set http connection as https, for example by using `HttpsURLConnection` for https communication.

Comment: Still receiving the same error on trying above two ways.Also tried changing the code to 
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        mStringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {@Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {System.out.println(response);}
 }, new Response.ErrorListener() 
{@Override  public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {System.out.println(error.toString()); }});
 mRequestQueue.add(mStringRequest);
But the code works fine for other api's.

Comment: I couldn't connect only to the api's running on my local machine.
P.S the IP address is the one to which both my android device and local machine are connected

Comment: And are you sure that the HTTPS is working well ? like certificate invalid or something

Comment: Yes other https requests are working fine with the above code. Only the api I developed in my local machine servlet isn't working and returns the message in image

Comment: Did you tried with something like postman ? To see if it's your API which create issue